# TestFlight build no longer compatible with iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone

Since a few weeks it seems that my app no longer supports the iPhone 4S hardware.
The deployment target is set to iOS 8.0. The iPhone 4S can have iOS 9... What am I missing here?
[image] [image]
[image]

Comment: No Marcus, I did not

Comment: no metal libraries in the project

Comment: It seems that the build was only made for arm64 :S, although armv7 is also selected in the build settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-Adding armv7 and armv7s with a new build solved the issue. (Still don't know why the architectures were removed.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the build was only made for 64 bit architectures???
Although my build settings request both arm64,armv7 and armv7s
[image: Xcode build settings]

TestFlight build states:
[image: TestFlight build info]

I'll rebuild the app and upload it again.

Comment: Looks like you may have built it in Debug mode. Debug mode has "Build Active Architecture Only" set to Yes. You could change that to No or build it for Release, which is what we usually do, since if it passes testing, we submit it.

Comment: Seems like that would be probable. Thx a lot Marcus!